# Python 3.8 install with Anaconda is Frozen on MacOS

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, virtualenv

Python 3.8.8 seems to be stuck on my macOS - how do I get rid of it? I trashed the 3.8 framework folder from Library then completely removed anaconda3. It's possible that I created a virtualenv using v3.8 so I tried to remove associated libraries and packages. Maybe I didn't do this correctly? I keep getting Python 3.8.8 when I check the version at the terminal. Your helpful kindness is greatly appreciated.

1. Removed Anaconda configs:

`conda install anaconda-clean`

`anaconda-clean --yes`

2. Removed the entire anaconda installation directory:

`rm -rf ~/anaconda3`

`rm -rf ~/.condarc ~/.conda ~/.continuum`

3. Removed virtualenv libraries
   `pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y`
4. Tried to remove all packages at once `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y`
5. Returned Python 3.8.8 after running `python --version`
6. Returned Frozen import errors after running `python -v`

[image: import _frozen_importlib # frozen ...]

**Solution with help below (comments)**

7. Checked location of python interpreter being used by my shell `which python`
8. Located traces of anaconda and removed it `rm -rf /Users/bls/opt/anaconda3`
9. Python 3.8.8 is finally GONE! `python --version`

   returns python 2.7.16

Comment: try running `which python` to see the location of the python interpreter your shell is using.

Comment: /Users/bls/opt/anaconda3/bin/python

Comment: looks like you missed some files when you tried to remove anaconda. Take a look at what is under `/Users/bls/opt/anaconda3` (and maybe move/rename instead of going straight to `rm -rf`)